# Debugging mako NameError("Undefined")

Tags: python, debugging, mako

Is there any way of obtaining more information about what happens when `NameError("Undefined")` is raised in Mako templates.

In [Flask-Mako](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mako/#error-handling) there is a solution, but I'm not using flask. So I need a *pure* Mako solution

Comment: To be clear, the question is about *how to diagnose* a particular type of problem, rather than what is specifically wrong in some specific situation, right? But even so, I think it would be easier to understand with some concrete examples (showing that you know what is wrong with them).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No. The question is how to know how to verbose more the errors `NameError` and so you can solve them

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is to use `strict_undefined=True` in `Template` instance (see [reference](https://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#mako.template.Template.params.strict_undefined))